# converting pyspark dataframe column values to list in DLT

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

How can we convert pyspark dataframe column values to list in DLT

I tried using `collect()` , `toPandas()`,collect_list(), toLocalIterator to converst dataframe df_year(has a column with year data only) to list but it is not supported in dlt pipeline. It's returing output as an empty list

```py
years = [row.YEAR  for row in df_year.collect() if row.YEAR is not None]

import pandas as pd

years = df_year.select("YEAR").toPandas()["YEAR"].tolist()
```

Comment: Why do you need it? Please update your question

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It's not returning any data..I am getting a blank list

Comment: Can you describe how you are using this code in DLT?